# I can't paste into my Dreamweaver Find and Replace window

Tags: macos, dreamweaver, replace

I'm using Dreamweaver CS5 on a Mac. I used to be able to do it but somehow all of a sudden it stopped working. If I copy something and paste it into a "Find and Replace" window, the window just blinks and becomes inactive.

I can type in the stuff that I'd like to paste but it means so much trouble, especially when I try to replace some long PHP codes etc. Would anyone who has a clue let me know how to fix this?

Many thanks indeed!!

L

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebuild the preferences per the Adobe KB article?

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83912.html

Typically, whenever Dreamweaver goes nuts on you rebuilding the preferences will fix it.